# Limit menu items available as possible parents on node creation

Tags: 7, routes

As I create a node I want to assign i to a menu item parent. I know that I can limit it to what menu(s) are available on:

> /admin/structure/types/manage/my_type

But it would narrow it down to "only some of the menu items". For instance if I have a menu like this:

> - Main menu
>
>   - Home (page)
>   - Service type A (page)
>   - Service type B (page)
>   - Service type C (page)
>   - About us (page)
>   - Contact us (page)

If I then have content type "Service", I don't want the editor to by mistake place the new node under About us. They should only be able to select "Service type A" (or B or C).

I would be nice if I just missed the module that does this trick.

Answer (score 0):

- For Drupal 6 there is http://drupal.org/project/node_menu_parent. A Drupal 7 version exists only as attachment in an issue: http://drupal.org/node/1138946
- You may consider http://drupal.org/project/menu_position which sets the active menu item when viewing the page based on certain rules.